# SWIG causing `symbol lookup issue` in perl package

Tags: c, perl, swig, undefined-symbol

I am trying to install an old perl module, called BioMol, where SWIG has been used to interface C with perl. It is currently installed on an 'old' machine and we want to install it on a newer machine.

I am able to build the package and install it on the newer machine - producing a single library:  BioMol.so.

When I try to run a sample script that uses a simple function from the perl module, I come across the following error:

`perl: symbol lookup error: /path-to-binary/BioMol.so: undefined symbol: new_fragmentlist`

By looking in the binary file (using nm), I found this:

```
 253                  U new_dihedrallist
 254 0000000000019f60 T new_DihedralList
 255                  U new_fragment
 256 0000000000017ca0 T new_Fragment
 257                  U new_fragmentlist
 258 0000000000019000 T new_FragmentList
```

So it is true that new_fragmentlist is undefined (L#257), however new_FragmentList (L#258) seems like the one I should be using anyway. The binary file that is on the 'old' machine looks like this:

```
896 0000000000018d00 T new_Dihedral
897 0000000000018c20 T new_DihedralList
898 00000000000170b0 T new_Fragment
899 0000000000016fd0 T new_FragmentList
```

I think this may be due to some rename directive in SWIG (see 5.4.7.2 in http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_rename_ignore). Maybe the reason I get the case issue in the new binary file, could be because of some new default option in the new SWIG (new version is 3.0.12 and the 'old machine' version is 1.3.40). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `BioMol` module? (I could not find it on metacpan.org)

Comment: Rename definitely shouldn't do that. Seems more like a linker error, but I can't quite understand how.

Comment: @HåkonHægland - The BioMol module was built in house a while back so it would not be available online.